# Is there any use for collecting extra BluGlo during a mission?

Tags: fortnite-save-the-world

While some quests (Ride the Lightning, Defend the Atlas, etc) require BluGlo to complete, others don't require any at all. Also, random objects on the map sometimes require BluGlo, like team buffs and radio towers. However, in one game, after encountering multiple trolls, I ended up with well over 20 BluGlo, which begged the question: is there any purpose for collecting this much BluGlo? There weren't enough team buffs or radio towers to use up all this BluGlo, but I'd certainly hate to collect all this BluGlo every mission for no reason.

Is there any benefit to stocking up BluGlo during a mission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this time the only uses for BluGlo outside of mission requirements are as you mentioned: Radar Towers (to scan for loot, mining locations etc), and Team Buff Stations (Fortitude, Movement Speed, Energy Boost etc).

I ended up giving up on hunting for BlueGlo outside of what I needed (although I find Radar Towers occasionally useful) because I just never used it.

I've read in a couple threads that BlueGlo used to have more use (like during a wave) in earlier versions, but have been removed at this state. I've also read that they're working on figuring out how to make it more rewarding or useful for gathering.

At the moment you can acquire it from Trolls, just laying about, around enemies, and from anomalies - so more than enough to go around, especially across many players.

> Edit - There is [supposedly](https://www.reddit.com/r/FORTnITE/comments/6pn2zi/to_all_the_people_doing_bluglo_siphons/) a quest that involves BluGlo gathering entirely, but that's not all that different from the missions like Ride the Lightning.

Comment: That's interesting. Do you know what the older versions used to have that incorporated Bluglo?

Comment: [It wasn't clear](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/forums/fortnite-discussion/general-discussion/29066-why-epic-why) and I can't find an exact answer on how it used to be included. Possibly because earlier testers/players had NDAs. "I'm pretty sure that's mostly something from earlier versions where BluGlo had uses even during waves"

Comment: It seemed like teleporters were using BluGlo after one thread I read, but in actuality it seems they're a gadget similar to supply drops.